# Network Latency: Does it make practical sense to use a cloud based redis/memcached solution

Tags: caching, networking, redis, memcached, administration

I came across this (and various others) while researching redis:
http://redis-cloud.com/

I am using redis with mongodb. I will be mostly using redis as a cache with very high number of reads. Does it make practical sense to use a cloud based solution? Personally, I believe network latency would play a spoil sport here if the redis server is in a different network (cloud based solution). The lag in fetching the data from the cloud redis server (in a different network) for each request would subvert/decrease the benefits of the caching layer (wouldn't it be better to wait a bit longer to fetch the records from mongo instead). Will I be able to reap maximum benefits if the redis server is in the same subnet?

Additionally, how difficult (administrative overhead) is it to run a redis server. Pardon me if I sound ignorant, as I do more of programming, and less of system administration work - so I prefer to ask the experts. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about network overhead with running just redis in the cloud, why not run your entire stack in the cloud, or just mongodb and redis in the cloud?

I checked out redis-cloud, and while interesting, I would not use it. The administrative overhead for redis is very low. You can deploy a redis master with multiple read slaves with little [effort](http://redis.io/topics/replication).